# how to use list(string) in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

I'm trying to use list(string) for azure event grid event types. I used to pass all the inputs using tfvars file. and use locals to get data from it.

Below is how the tfvars looks like.

```html
grid_configuration = {
  grid1 = {
    name                   = "testgridsiai"
    rg-name                = "sai-india"
    location               = "uksouth"
    is_storage_grid        = true
    source_storage_account = "apmapplicationstorages"
    topic_subscription = [
      {
        is_sink_queue                                = true
        is_sink_eventhub                             = true
        storage_account_name                         = "apmapplicationstorages"
        storage_account_queue_name                   = "asset-data"
        storage_account_queue_name_subscription_name = "store"
        event_hub_name                               = "input"
        event_hub_namespace_name                     = "SIAI-EH-NEW-APMS"
        event_hub_subscription_name                  = "event-test"
                event_types                                   = ["Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated","Microsoft.Storage.BlobDeleted"]

      }
      
      ]
      }
      }
```

and below is the terraform configuration

```html
locals {
  grid_topics = { for e in var.grid_configuration : e.name => e }

  subscriptions = { for hc in flatten([for h in var.grid_configuration :
    [for c in h.topic_subscription : {
      is_sink_queue                                = c.is_sink_queue
      is_sink_eventhub                             = c.is_sink_eventhub
      storage_account_name                         = c.storage_account_name
      storage_account_queue_name                   = c.storage_account_queue_name
      event_hub_name                               = c.event_hub_name
      grid_name                                    = h.name
      location                                     = h.location
      rg-name                                      = h.rg-name
      storage_account_queue_name_subscription_name = c.storage_account_queue_name_subscription_name
      event_hub_namespace_name                     = c.event_hub_namespace_name
      event_hub_subscription_name                  = c.event_hub_subscription_name
      event_types                                  = c.event_types
  }]]) : format("%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s", hc.is_sink_queue, hc.is_sink_eventhub, hc.storage_account_name, hc.storage_account_queue_name, hc.event_hub_name, hc.grid_name, hc.rg-name, hc.location, hc.event_hub_namespace_name, hc.event_hub_subscription_name, hc.event_types) => hc }

}

resource "azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription" "example" {
  for_each = { for k, v in local.subscriptions : k => v if v.is_sink_queue }

  name                = each.value.storage_account_queue_name_subscription_name
  system_topic        = each.value.grid_name
  resource_group_name = each.value.rg-name
  storage_queue_endpoint {
    storage_account_id = data.azurerm_storage_account.example[each.key].id
    queue_name         = each.value.storage_account_queue_name
  }
  included_event_types = [each.value.event_types]
  depends_on           = [azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic.example]

}
```

and below is the error

```html
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on event-grid/main.tf line 18, in locals:
│   18:   }]]) : format("%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s", hc.is_sink_queue, hc.is_sink_eventhub, hc.storage_account_name, hc.storage_account_queue_name, hc.event_hub_name, hc.grid_name, hc.rg-name, hc.location, hc.event_hub_namespace_name, hc.event_hub_subscription_name, hc.event_types) => hc }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ hc.event_hub_name is "input"
│     │ hc.event_hub_namespace_name is "SIAI-EH-NEW-APMS"
│     │ hc.event_hub_subscription_name is "event-test2"
│     │ hc.event_types is list of string with 2 elements
│     │ hc.grid_name is "testgridsiai"
│     │ hc.is_sink_eventhub is true
│     │ hc.is_sink_queue is true
│     │ hc.location is "uksouth"
│     │ hc.rg-name is "sai-india"
│     │ hc.storage_account_name is "apmapplicationstorages"
│     │ hc.storage_account_queue_name is "channel-data"
│
│ Call to function "format" failed: unsupported value for "%s" at 30: string required.
```

I understood that I needed to use formatlist() instead of format(). Can someone throw some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add [...](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments):

```
format("%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s", hc.is_sink_queue, hc.is_sink_eventhub, hc.storage_account_name, hc.storage_account_queue_name, hc.event_hub_name, hc.grid_name, hc.rg-name, hc.location, hc.event_hub_namespace_name, hc.event_hub_subscription_name, hc.event_types...)
```

Comment: i got below error,          │ Error: Invalid function argument
│
│   on event-grid/main.tf line 18, in locals:
│   18:   }]]) : format("%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s.%s", hc.is_sink_queue, hc.is_sink_eventhub, hc.storage_account_name, hc.storage_account_queue_name, hc.event_hub_name, hc.grid_name, hc.rg-name, hc.location, hc.event_hub_namespace_name, hc.event_hub_subscription_name, hc.event_types...) => hc }
│
│ Invalid value for "args" parameter: too many arguments; only 11 used by format string.
╵

Comment: @Prabhin So add one more `%s`. You need as many `s`es as you have arguments.

Comment: still im getting below error.   ╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on event-grid/main.tf line 109, in resource "azurerm_eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription" "example":
│  109:   included_event_types = [each.value.event_types]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.event_types is list of string with 2 elements
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "included_event_types": element 0: string required.

Comment: @Prabhin This is new issue. My answer correctly addresses the original problem you reported.

Comment: actually I'm looking for a solution where my terraform accepts a list of string for event-grid.